# Division of two numbers always returns an integer value

Tags: c++

Using the formula "(4/3)*3.14*pow(radius,3)", the number returned always yields to an integer. Any ideas on how to get a floating point number from the formula?

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float radius, v;
    cout<<"Enter value of radius";cin>>radius;
    v = (4/3)*3.14*pow(radius, 3);
    cout<<"volume of sphere: "<<v<<endl;
    system("pause");return 0;
}
```

Comment: 4/3 results in an integer, not a float.

Comment: I would have thought there are zillions of duplicates, but had no luck finding a good one ...

Comment: Btw, if you care about efficiency, you should avoid using `pow()` for small integer powers, in particular if they are known at compile time. The most efficient way to compute the volume of the 3-sphere is `4.188790204786391*r*r*r`, which is just 3 multiplications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is 1 because, 4 and 3 are integers, and in C++ integer divided by integer yields another integer, so 4/3 = 1.

But to correct that, all you need to do is this, 
Change the integer to a floating point decimal number, for e.g. 4 could be written as 4.0 instead.

```
(4.0/3)*3.14*pow(radius,3)
```

Thats all and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `4/3` performs *integer* division, and will result in `1` (it results in truncation of any decimals). You should be performing *floating point* division.

```
v = (4.0/3.0)*3.14*pow(radius, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

As 4 and 3 both are integers as their division will also be an integer, to obtain the floating point value as a result, you need to specify both the values to be float (i.e 4.0 and 3.0)
By applying above you will end up something like this
(4.0/3.0)=floating point value.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read the existing answers before posting your own. Your answer is a clone of the accepted answer.