# setprecision(2) value not working in if statement even when the conditions are true

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-c++, iomanip

I dont understand why setprecision(2) not working when using if else statement

I tried doing this and it displays the else statement. I dont see any problem, maybe im using setprecision() wrong? I even displayed the quotient to prove that the if statement should be the one running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x = 2;
    float y = 3;
    float quotient, answer;
    quotient = x / y;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << quotient << " (is the answer)\n";
    cout << " What is " << x << " divided by " << y << " ? ";
    cin >> answer; // answer should be 0.67
    
     if (quotient == answer)
     cout << " You got the right answer! ";
     else
     cout << " Nice Try :( ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting `setprecision` to change the actual value of `quotient`?

Comment: [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division) and [Division of two numbers always returns an integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973406/division-of-two-numbers-always-returns-an-integer-value)

Comment: I changed the x and y to float data type now but it still wont do the if statement...

Comment: yes I want to change the actual value of the quotient. Its just that there are some division problems where the answer is infinite so I need to avoid that and thought setprecision is the right thing to do

Comment: @ErvinPejo No you misunderstood what `setprecision` does. It changes the way numbers are printed, not the way that calculations are done.

Comment: Sorry I am still new with c++ and dont know other way to change the value of the quotient to only 2 decimal places and I cant use the round() since I need the 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
quotient = x / y;
```

will assign the value of `0.0` to the variable `quotient`, because `2/3` is `0`, using the rules of integer division. Therefore, if the user enters `0.67`, this value will not compare equal to `0.0`.

If you want the division `2/3` to evaluate to something like `0.6666666667`, then you must make at least one of the operands a floating-point number, for example by using a cast:

```
quotient = static_cast<float>(x) / y;
```

However, even if you did this, your comparison would still not work, because the expression

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << quotient;
```

will only change the way the variable `quotient` is printed. It will not change the actual value of the variable.

In order to round the actual value of the variable, you can use the function [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round). Note that this will only round to the nearest integer, so if you want to round to the nearest multiple of `0.01`, then you will first have to multiply the number by `100` before performing the rounding operation. If you want, you can then divide the number by `100` again, to get the original number again, rounded to the nearest multiple of `0.01`.

However, you should be aware that these operations may introduce slight [floating-point inaccuracies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/12149471). For this reason, it may be better to not require an exact match in the comparison

```
if (quotient == answer)
```

but to consider a deviation of up to `0.01` to still be considered a match. You can do this for example by changing the expression to this:

```
if ( std::abs( quotient - answer ) < 0.01 )
```

Note that you will have to `#include <cmath>` in order to use `std::round` and `std::abs`.

Comment: I changed x and y to float now but yeah like what you said it wont work. Is there a way to change the value of the quotient to 2 decimal places only? because I am making a game where you will solve arithmetic equations but there are just some division problems where the answer is infinite or too long. any solution?

Comment: @ErvinPejo: I have now edited my question to provide further information. I believe that this addtional information answers the question that you asked in your previous comment.